# How to check if Windows Universal 10 app is closed not minimised?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10-universal

Hi guys I am aware that OnSuspending function in the app.xaml file allows me to save information should my app be suspended. I want my user to be automatically logged out in my database should the application be closed by the user. Here is my code:

```
 private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        if (CommonVariables.LoggedIn)
        {
            CommonVariables.LoggedIn = false;
            string jsonPayload = "{\"user_id\":\"" + CommonVariables.AuthenticateUserResponseDetails.user.id + "\"}";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string postUrl = CommonVariables.SERVER + CommonVariables.LogOut;
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, postUrl);
            //encrypt tase

            EDecrypt encrypt = new EDecrypt();
            jsonPayload = encrypt.AES_Encrypt(jsonPayload, CommonVariables.EncryptionKey);

            request.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonPayload)));
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string response = string.Empty;
        }

        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

This works for me well so when my user closes the app in their device the function is called and they are logged out. However my issue the function also logs the user out when they minimise the app or put the app to the background and go into another app. So how can I adjust my code so that my logout function only works when the user shuts down the app in their device?

Comment: You can't.  Core feature of WinRT (aka UWP) is that your process can get terminated instantly after it is suspended.  Happens whenever the OS needs RAM for other processes.  The "instantly" clause prevents anything similar to what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

When you minimize an app, there are actually 2 things happening:

- [Visibility change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-visibility)
- [App suspension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-suspend)

> When the user switches from your app to another app, your app is no
>   longer visible but remains in the Running state until Windows suspends
>   it. If the user switches away from your app but activates or switches
>   back to it before it can suspended, the app remains in the Running
>   state.

So if a user minimizes/switches to another app and comes back fast enough, your app will keep running and your `OnSuspending` handler will never execute. While being in the background, the OS will determine when your app goes to suspension and when/if it is terminated (like Hans mentioned in his comment).

---

So to fix your problem: keep your `OnSuspending` handler, and handle the [app resume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-resume) event to log back in. This will cover both minimizing and closing.

Comment: Try to implement a Background Task, where you can respond to some system events like UserAway, UserPresent and so on : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224839